# undefined reference error when overloading

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

So I looked around here for answers to this question, but none of the solutions worked for me. I have overloaded the operator << in a separate class "Operators.cpp" The exact code is as follows:

```
#include "Rolo.h"
#include "RoloHeader.h"
#include "RoloParsedRecord.h"
#include "RoloRawRecord.h"


std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outstream, const Rolo& rolo){
    string roloData = rolo.toString();
    outstream << roloData;
    return outstream;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outstream, const RoloHeader& roloHeader){
    string roloHeaderData = roloHeader.toString();
    outstream << roloHeaderData;
    return outstream;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outstream, const RoloParsedRecord& rpRecord){
    string rpRecordData = rpRecord.toString();
    outstream << rpRecordData;
    return outstream;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outstream, const RoloRawRecord& rrRecord){
    string rrRecordData = rrRecord.toString();
    outstream << rrRecordData;
    return outstream;
}
```

In Rolo.h:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Rolo& rolo);
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const RoloHeader& roloHeader);
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const RoloParsedRecord& rpRecord);
```

It is called in the Main.cpp as:

```
Rolo theRolo;
theRolo.readRolo(inStream); //no issues here
theRolo.sortRolo(sortTag); //no issues here either
outStream << theRolo.toStringFormatted(); //prints out exactly as wanted, no issues
outStream << theRolo; //this is where it chokes
```

When I compile it, I get:

```
Main.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3f9): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Rolo&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Aprog] Error 1
```

There are other classes, which run perfectly. The issue only comes up when I try and use the overloaded << as opposed to the toStringFormatted() function.

So my question is: What is going wrong here? Why is it undefined? And, most importantly, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you compile this? Do you compile and link seperate?
What you possibly do: You say to Main.cpp that there is overloaded operator by including Rolo.h. It compiles. But linker cannot find its implementation.

Comment: That is exactly it. I should have realized it was something so simple. I had to add it to the makefile. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write the scope of operator while defining the function. Shouldn't it be `std::ostream& Rolo::operator <<(std::ostream& outstream, const Rolo& rolo)`